# HTML text doesn't print to screen when using canvas in conjunction

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

In this snippet of code, even though I align the text far outside of the canvas boundaries, the text shows up below the canvas height.  I'm new to HTML and I question why using a canvas seems to block the whole row it's on.  I also want to know if there is a way around this, so I can have my canvas and have the text to the right of it on the same row.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<canvas id= "myCanvas" width="600" height="600">
</canvas>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.6" />
</head>
<body>
<p style="text-align:right">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: that's an odd place to put a canvas - `<html>` elements have the following **Permitted Content** - `One <head> element, followed by one <body> element`, so you have invalid HTML for a start - you'll want the canvas to be an `display:inline-block` or perhaps use `float:left`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML is invalid and cannot work this way.

Comment: I don't see what Jaromanda is talking about. I use one `<head`, it closes later with a `</head>`.  And you say it won't work, yet it's worked perfectly fine for me so far.

Comment: @Rob, while it's true this markup is invalid, DOM has rules for documents recovery : here the canvas will be placed in the `<body>` because it is not allowed in head... So yes, it unfortunately can work this way... And to OP, to get valid markup, you must have **only, and in this order** "*One <head> element, followed by one <body> element*" It can't be anything else. Even an comment node is not valid.

Comment: So I'm hearing closing tags are not necessary for `<body>` and `<head>`? Because, I've seen a lot of code that include closing tags, including some of the example code listed in this thread

Comment: @Kalido That browsers are required to do the best they can with invalid markup, errors in code are errors and ignoring or dismissing them is the mark of an amateur and a fool.

Comment: @BradyBess If you wish not to learn how to write proper HTML, SO is not the place for you. You will continue to struggle with it on a daily basis and never accomplish anything. Your question, as the markup was originally, is not answerable or fixable.

Comment: And again you are asking for a hack to fix your broken markup rather than learning ​the right way to do things. SO is not about amateur hacks

Comment: Still waiting for you to give actual advice on WHAT I'm doing wrong, as everyone else hasn't commented on it being broken

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="BBEdit 11.6" />
</head>

<body>
  <p style="text-align:right; display: inline-block;">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: His and your HTML is invalid and will not work at all.

Comment: This does in fact work, but it prints the text at the bottom right of the canvas.  Anyway I can get it aligned with the top right of the canvas?

Comment: flex in a wrapping div will automatically align it at the top like you're asking Brady.  if you want to change the alignment further, you could then use align-content.

Answer (score 0):

First your code is some wrong, you need to follow a structure.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Code -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Code -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Your canvas you need to write inside body tag.
You have many options but each options have differences, depend of what you want to do after, you can to choose :

`float`, `inline`, `inline-block` or `inline-flex`

**Float:**

This is the old form, that make an element float.

```html
<canvas style="float:left; border:1px solid red;" id= "myCanvas" width="30" height="30">
</canvas>
<p style="text-align:right">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
```

**Inline:**

Element in one line but doesn't respect the width and height property of the element.

```html
<canvas style="border:1px solid red;" id= "myCanvas" width="30" height="30">
</canvas>
<p style="display:inline;">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
```

**Inline-block:**

Element in one line respecting the width and height property of the element.

```html
<canvas style="border:1px solid red;" id= "myCanvas" width="30" height="30">
</canvas>
<p style="display:inline-block;">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
```

**Inline-Flex:**

Introduced in css3, inline in version flex.

```html
<canvas style="border:1px solid red;" id= "myCanvas" width="30" height="30">
</canvas>
<p style="display:inline-flex;">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
```

The definitions are very quickly, refer more information:

[Reference 1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=example)

[Reference 2](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

**Update:**

Align in the top, using flex:

```html
<div style="display:flex;align-self: flex-start">
  <canvas style="border:1px solid red;" id= "myCanvas" width="100" height="100">
  </canvas>
  <p style="margin-top:0">JavaScript can change the content of an HTML element:</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, but the text is at the bottom right of the canvas.  Do you know how I could get it aligned with the top of the canvas?

Comment: @BradyBess I updated the code, align with the top of the canvas, if you want to make modifications you can read more about flex in the references or google. Remember that research is better than having all easy.